# Date Array with Different Value in SQL Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I need to Get all the values(Left Join) from the `Questiontable` which Include t
the dates in the Declared table .
But Somehow i am only able to pull only records where this condition is met:

```
Q.Author_ID = S.Author_id
```

What do i change in the query for it to give me all the results in for 4 weeks of data before the `sent_date`

***SQL Query***

```
Declare @Sample_Alankar Table
(
 Author_id int,
 Sent_date Datetime,
 Fixed_Date datetime
)
Declare @StartDate DateTime
Declare @EndDate DateTime
Declare @NumofWeeks Int

Set @NumofWeeks = 4 -- change this to the number of days you are interested in...say pros responding to atleast one question in last "60" days
Set @StartDate = '7/1/2013'
Set @EndDate =  '9/1/2013'

insert @Sample_Alankar values 
(63977546,'11/5/2013','11/13/2013'),
(61534878,'11/5/2013','11/13/2013'),
(59725966,'11/4/2013','11/13/2013'),
(30945867,'9/18/2013','9/25/2013'),
(10263656,'11/4/2013','11/13/2013'),
(59685895,'9/3/2013','9/10/2013'),
(28732269,'11/5/2013','11/6/2013'),
(12711280,'11/4/2013','11/12/2013'),
(11292137,'11/4/2013','11/12/2013'),
(66248244,'11/4/2013','11/12/2013')

;With Cte_Sent_Date as 
(
Select distinct Q.topic_id,Author_id
from QuestionResponse Q
Left join @Sample_Alankar S on Q.Author_ID = S.Author_id

where 
1 = 1 
and  First_Start_date between DATEADD(WEEK,@NumofWeeks*(-1),Sent_date) and Sent_date
```

Comment: where is your `QuestionResponse` table ?Please post it's schema too.

Comment: I dont have the schema but All i My result is topic_id Author_id
11500310 11292137
13171508 59685895
13224725 10263656
13277539 59685895
13282148 11292137
13299872 59685895
13301051 59685895
13302671 59685895
13303432 59685895
13303565 59685895
13305230 59685895                                                        I need some nULL values in the author_id coloumn As left Join is intended to do .

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct Q.topic_id,S.Author_id
from QuestionResponse Q
Left join @Sample_Alankar S on Q.Author_ID = S.Author_id
```

Comment: Could you also explain how can i use the where clause to only select dates in sent_date column from my declared table.

Comment: @user3156213 If you only want to select dates from `sent_date` column use `IN` clause , Like `Where date in (select sent_date from tablename)` However i didn't get what is your requirement and i do not know if `left Join` will respond correctly with this condition but give it a try .

Comment: Well my requirement is i want my query to give me result for date range of the sent_date and fixed date column.

Comment: @user3156213 I do not have your second table information, but check this if it helps you, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36796c7/5